# Java program that will print in ladder form based on user input

Tags: java, algorithm

I am beginner in Java programming and I want to print characters based on user input but I am not getting the right output.

```
    char any;
    double b;
    double c;
    double n;

    System.out.print("Input character(s): ");
    any = kets.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.print("Input range: ");
    n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

    for(b=1; b<=n; b++)
    {
        for(c=1; c<=b; c++)
        {
            System.out.print(any);

        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The Output I am getting:

```
Input character(s): JSP
Input range: 5
J
JJ
JJJ
JJJJ
JJJJJ
```

The Output Should be:

```
Input character(s): JSP
Input range: 5
JSP
JSP JSP
JSP JSP JSP
JSP JSP JSP JSP
JSP JSP JSP JSP JSP
```

Comment: a `char` can only hold 1 character. If you want a sequence of characters, use a `String`

Comment: Use `String any;` instead of `char any;`, and then use `any = kets.next();` instead of `any = kets.next().charAt(0);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a String to store your input, not a `char`. Your current code looks to store the first letter of the user's entry: `.charAt(0);` You can find the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)).

A `char` may only store one character at a time, whereas a String may hold much more (up to 2,147,483,647 characters, also read as  2^31 -1)

```
String any; //Change any from type char to String
double b;
double c;
double n;

System.out.print("Input character(s): ");
any = kets.next(); 
//Retrieve just the next() String..no need to delve deeper for a character.
System.out.print("Input range: ");
n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

for(b=1; b<=n; b++)
{
    for(c=1; c<=b; c++)
    {
        System.out.print(any);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because of `any = kets.next().charAt(0);`

This line will `return` the `character` at **0th position of next token** .

So for the **Input String**  "JSP". 
-- `kets.next().charAt(0);' will return : **J**

If you want the whole `token` , just use `String any = kets.next();`

Hope your doubts are clear.

Comment: Purpose of SO is to make understand the OP its mistakes, not just to give the correct answer, so that OP doesn't have problem in future. Hope the above answer clear your doubts.